# How to use multiple columns in a list-group-item of a Bootstrap accordion?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How does one use columns in the list items that expand out when an accordion is opened in Bootstrap (3)?  I am trying to keep it simple, and just use the grid classes in list-group-items as divs, as in using the `col-sm-3` class.

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8RgrrXBy1h).

Excerpted, the accordion list-group-items look like this:

```
<div id="One" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-One">
    <div class="list-group">
                 <a class="list-group-item col-sm-3" href="#">a</a>
                <div class="list-group-item col-sm-3">b</div>
                <div class="list-group-item col-sm-3">c</div>
                <div class="list-group-item col-sm-3">d</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The trouble is that when the accordions open, they don't get their height sized properly, and bleed into each other.  I've tried adding a clearfix div under each list-group, but there are some weird artifacts with the first list-group-item border then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the bootstrap documentation

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

and

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

Just add the row and container classes in the proper places and you'll have it.

Updated bootply - http://www.bootply.com/LQgHemNzZr

Comment: That looks just about like when I added clearfix divs.  In other words, the list-group-item rows extend beyond the accordion horizontally, and the vertical boarders are overwritten.  Also, the first column in the first row of each list-group seems to place the top horizontal border at the bottom of the row.  I actually had the outer container div already, but I see you made the accordion use both panel-group and list-group classes.  I'll try putting some explicit row divs in, to see if that helps get the columns their expected parent container.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. Change the 3 containers to container-fluid then. http://www.bootply.com/Sq6PMkM9L9

Comment: Yep, that made it much better.  So here is the summary.  The parent accordion needed to be a panel-group, not a list-group (my typo).  To get columns in the list-group-items, I needed to make each collapsable panel use the container-fluid class.  Also, the list-group divs in each panel needed to use the row class.  To fix row 1, column 1 borders, I needed to insert a clear-fix right before the list-group.  At that point, it looks good enough.  See the end result here http://www.bootply.com/JsrMTohJJT.